# How to handle collective subscriptions (i.e. for companies and like)

Tags: payment, subscription

I have a website and some content of the website is restricted to paying users having a subscription. You can subscribe as a single user, but there is also the option to purchase a "collective subscription" for companies, schools, universities etc.

For example: A company wants to have access for one year for 100 users.

My question: How do I handle subscriptions / access in these cases?

Ideas:

1. After receiving the payment I could hand some code to the company. Entering this code, 100 users can subscribe.

Advantage: It's easy.
Disadvantage: If only one user gives the code to some external user and the code is used by other persons, the company will have less than 100 users to be subscribed.

2. After receiving the payment I could hand 100 different codes to company. The company hands each of the users one of the codes. With this individual code each user can subscribe.

Advantage: The problem of 1. can't happen here.
Disadvantage: It's complicated for the company to send 100 codes to different users (i. e. per email). If I give the codes as a perforated paper its probably impossible to hand over the codes because maybe not all users are located at the same place.

3. The company hands me a list of all users (i. e. names or email). After receiving the payment, I send each user a code. With this code each user can subscribe.

Advantage: Not the problems of 1. and 2. Disadvantage: The company (or school, university ...) has to know beforehand all users which is not realistic. I will get many inquiries afterwards with more and more names to subscribe.

4. After receiving the payment I send a code to the company. All users can subscribe with the code if they use a special comapny email address xxxxx@companyname.com

Advantage: None the problems 1, 2, 3 (or maybe 1, but the code can only be used internal in the company)
Disadvantage: I cannot expect every client to have a uniform email address (i.e. if its not a company but a school, university ...)

Any hints about this? Any other ideas? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Is it possible to give an administrative user at the company a list of all the users who have used their code? If so, you could implement option 1, the most user friendly by far, but give the company the ability to audit that no unauthorized users have received the code. You might get some inquiries after the fact, but likely not as many as with option 3.

Answer (score 1):

To me, the only ones that present problems are options 2, 3, and 4 for what is written in the question. However, I don't see any problem with option 1. If a user gives the code to someone outside the company and the company loses one of the hundred users, it's not a problem in the website but rather an internal problem in the company/client.

Perhaps it's necessary to make the clarification on the web before delivering the codes:

> This website delivers these one hundred codes exclusively for the users assigned by the company/client and is not responsible for their misuse.

---

In the same way that a user can give their code to someone outside the company that has acquired them, there can be hundreds of similar conflicts and none of them is the responsibility of the person who delivered those codes.

Comment: In this case, the 'code' could work much like an affiliate link. When you follow the link and sign up, you're automatically added to ("affiliated with") the company to which the link belongs. One note though; offering a portal to manage users (i.e. block / remove unwanted users from your group) is pretty much a hard requirement in all situations. You might even want to add an option to generate a new code, should the current one become too publicized.